# What do the numbers after a note mean?

Tags: sheet-music

What does B5 and B4 mean?[image]

Is it referring to the bar number or the octave in which the note is present?

So is this B a B4?
[image]

Comment: Letter names are really exactly what is said, letters for names. I have not seen any theory where you are expected to add the octave in your answer.

Comment: But does it represent the octave

Comment: Octave designation is actually VERY common in music theory.

Comment: Yeah, poorly-written question on the assignment IMO. Anyone asks me "what letter name was that", my response is 'B' - the letter's name! Octaves are important, but if they wanted the scientific pitch designation they should have said so.

Answer (score 1):

It is called scientific pitch notation. From [wikipedia we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation):

> Scientific pitch notation (or SPN, also known as American Standard
>   Pitch Notation (ASPN) and International Pitch Notation (IPN))[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation) is a
>   method of specifying musical pitch by combining a musical note name
>   (with accidental if needed) and a number identifying the pitch's
>   octave.

So the number is the octave. Middle C is in octave 4.

Answer (score 0):

**4** and **5** represent the octave! Letter **B** means it's a **B** note.
[image]

The same way you say play the sequence C2-G2-C3-C2-G2-Bb2-Eb2-F2-G2 in a 4/4.

Comment: Does B4 mean middle B/the B after middle C?

Comment: Middle C is mostly C4 (though sometimes C3) and B4 is a C5 flat.